# How to do smoothing of 3D images based on millimeter?

Tags: matlab, gaussian, smoothing

I am simulating a paper that the scale of smoothing of images is based on millimeter. The format of 3D images is DICOM. For example, normally the smoothing of image ***X*** with window ***size*** and scale ***s***, is being done as follows:

```
f1 = fspecial('gaussian',[size,size],s);
Smooth1 = imfilter(X,f1);
```

Does anybody know how can I do smoothing which its scale is based millimeter?

Should I change the size of window based on millimeter instead of pixel? How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe http://forums.dcm4che.org/jiveforums/thread.jspa?threadID=1732

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the shape of the Gaussian filter to be defined in millimeters, you can use the `PixelSpacing` property from the DICOM metadata to convert millimeters to pixels. The units of the `PixelSpacing` is `mm/pixel`

```
info = dicominfo(filename);
X = double(dicomread(info));

scale_mm = 3;                                           % Signma of the filter in mm

scale_px = scale_mm / double(info.PixelSpacing(1));     % Converted to pixels

% Create a Gaussian filter using this sigma value
f1 = fspecial('gaussian', [height, width], scale_px);

% Apply the smoothing
smooth1 = imfilter(X, f1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, what is the usage of scale_mm here?  and what is sz?

Comment: @S.EB Sorry, Had a typo from an old version. Fixed now

Comment: Thank you so much Suever :)